# What's the song that starts playing at 20:20 in the last my hero academia episode ? (S5 E7)

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

On My Hero Academia season 5 episode 7 from about 20:20, there's an OST playing in the background that I can't seem to track down and I could use some help.

What's that song?

Answer (score 1):

That song is Sakusen Kaishi!(作戦開始!) from Yuki Hayashi(林ゆうき), this song was also used in the movie "My hero academia The Movie Heroes:Rising".

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95wfzvJovSk) is the YouTube video from the original YouTube Channel